# How to use partials in Express.js layout?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a layout.ejs file that contains my site's basic boilerplate HTML markup: doctype declaration, head, body, footer, the basics...

How would I go about placing the navigation in a separate partial file and including it into this layout? Is there a particular require() or include() function for doing this?

I am using EJS view engine.

Comment: This depends on the view engine you're using. Express doesn't define anything for this itself, but EJS does. If you change view engines, say to Jade or Handlebars, you'll have to use their own approaches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

```
<% include path/to/template %>
```

Documentation here. https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs#includes

Answer (score 8):

I came across similar issue with handlebars template, working with expressjs 4.0

In my app.js:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');

// register path to partials
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
```

Then add a partial file to your partials dir:

```
/views/partials/nav.hbs
```

You could then call it within e.g index.hbs like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    {{> nav}}
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In case if i have multiple partials, how i can render each partial on a corresponding button click in express js?

Answer (score 0):

```
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.engine( 'hbs', hbs( {
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultView: 'default',
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/',
  partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/'
}));
```

see: [page templates](https://hackersandslackers.com/handlebars-templates-expressjs/)